# What is the better way to create a drag and drop table in rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drag-and-drop

I am working on rails. In one of my views I need to create a list that can be sorted by drag and drop way. I have found [this way](http://benw.me/posts/sortable-bootstrap-tables/) on google. But in that tutorial they used `act_as_list` gem. according to the documentation of this gem it is;

> An ActiveRecord plugin for managing lists. http://swanandp.github.io/acts_as_list/

I am using `mongoid` . Please, can anyone suggest how I can create a drag and drop list in rails views for `mongoDB`?

Comment: have you understand my question @Stefan

Comment: i would like to do similarly like this http://sortable-bootstrap-table-rails.herokuapp.com/ @Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create drag and drop table using the gem jquery-ui-rails. here you can find more info [here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

using jquery i have done like this

```
    jQuery(function($) {
  if ($('#table_body_id').length > 0) {
    table_width = $('#table_body_id').width();
    cells = $('.table').find('tr')[0].cells.length;
    desired_width = table_width / cells + 'px';
    $('.table td').css('width', desired_width);
  }

  $('#table_body_id').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: '.table-responsive',
    sort: function(e, ui) {
      ui.item.addClass('active-item-shadow');
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      ui.item.removeClass('active-item-shadow');
      ui.item.children('td').effect('highlight', {}, 1000);
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var all_row_ids = $(this).sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'table_row_id' });
      $.ajax({
        url: 'my_url_to_sort',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          ids: all_row_ids
        },
        success: function(){
          $('#table_body_id > tr').each(function(i, tr) {
            $('.index:first', this).html(i + 1);
          });

          console.log("success");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

now in controller action we can sort out data with position field like this

```
    def sort
      params[:ids].each_with_index do |id, index|
      ModelName.where(id: id).update(position: index+1)
    end

    render nothing: true
  end
```

Thank you.